# Mongoose add filter to insert in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a array of data need to be inserted to mongodb. But the array has some data have already existed in mongodb. How to insert this array of data only the parts which not existed in mongodb. The struct is like below:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("551ca2b973d1124a0445f491"),
        "url" : "http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/ddf0f092gw1eqqyykbezwg20bu06px6u.gif",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-04-02T02:00:25.395Z"),
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("551ca2b973d1124a0445f492"),
        "url" : "http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/thumbnail/ddf0f092jw1eqqyz3c2bfg20b4068hdz.gif",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-04-02T02:00:25.401Z"),
        "__v" : 0
    }
]
```

For example the first document's url has already existed in mongodb, how to add a filter or exclude it from the array and then insert it into the mongodb.

My current insert code like below:

```
var imgDicts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var img = imgs[i].img;
    var imgDict = {url: img, createdAt: Date.now()};
    imgDicts.push(imgDict);
};
console.log(imgDicts);
Img.collection.insert(imgDicts, function(err, docs){
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, {message: 'success'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it with `db.collection.find()` API? Just do this call and if not found, insert. Here is the link http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: @akshay I know this. But is there any other smart way to do this?

Comment: Define "smart" way. Doesn't the above code solve what you're looking for?

Comment: @akshay In your case, I will have to write a for loop, in the for loop I will do a find and then remove the document from the data array. and then insert. Just think about this, it's too primeval.

Comment: even to exclude, you need to iterate over all your img. I do not think you can do this by just sending a list/object to mongoose to check if exists

Comment: try $set with update. Ex- db.collection.update({ _id : ObjectId("YOUR_OBJECT_ID")}, { $set : { key1 : value1 , key2 : value2 }}, function(result) { //your code after updation})

Comment: @Nielarshi I am not trying to update document. I want to insert new documents and leave the old document alone.

Comment: You could use the upsert flag on the db.collection.update method. This would insert new records, and update existing ones...But given your previous comment, would I be right in thinking that you absolutely don't want to touch existing records?

Comment: @justcompile I don't want to touch existing records.